# Correct way of defining routes when using paths loaded from an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

```
const App = () => {
  const url = `${urlApi}gallery`;
  const [dataChange, setDataChange] = useState(false);
  const { data } = useFetchGet(url, dataChange);

  return (
    <div className ='app'>
      <h1 className='app-header'>XYZ</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route 
            element={<HomePage setDataChange={setDataChange} dataChange={dataChange} />}
            path='/'
          />
          {data && data.galleries.map((oneElement) => {
            const { path } = oneElement
            return(
              <Route 
                key={path} 
                path={`/:${path}`}
                element={
                  <TitleContext.Provider value={path}>
                    <PageLayout title={path} />
                  </TitleContext.Provider>
                }
              />
            )
          })}
          <Route 
            path='*'
            element={<NotFoundPage />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

I import the `useFetch` custom hook into the component through which it downloads data from the API, and I get a path route from the data. Is this the correct way of defining routes when using paths loaded from an API?

Comment: If you are focused on optimizing performance, then consider implementing a process that allows for the simultaneous execution of fetch requests alongside the route rendering. I highly recommend reading the article ["React Query meets React Router."](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-meets-react-router) It offers valuable insights that could greatly benefit your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to say no, it's not the correct way to load routes from an API.

If you want to render a route for each "path" value that was fetched/mapped then you'll use the "path" value directly.

```
{data?.galleries.map((oneElement) => {
  const { path } = oneElement;

  return (
    <Route 
      key={path} 
      path={path} // <-- use path value directly
      element={
        <TitleContext.Provider value={path}>
          <PageLayout title={path} />
        </TitleContext.Provider>
      }
    />
  )
})}
```

If you use a dynamic path segment, e.g. `` path={`/:${path}`} ``, then each route would have its own unique path parameter and the routed component would need to know what the path value was in order to extract the path parameter... that said, if the routed component has that value then it already has it and wouldn't need to access the path params.

Comment: @loomi.dev Are you saying that ```path={`/:${path}`}``` *did* actually work in your case? The difference is what the path value actually is. For example, if the paths are `["foo", "bar", ...]` and use my suggestion then the paths are matchable to `"/foo"`, `"/bar"`, etc. If you use your code they would be `"/:foo"`, `"/:bar"`, etc. Do you see the difference? The former would match the values exactly while the latter are dynamic path segments that all have the same specificity, only 1 path can be matched, likely the first route in the array. Does this make sense?

Comment: @loomi.dev Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: ok sorry, is path={path} the correct way to use it according to the router's documentation?

Comment: The [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration) takes a `path` prop that is a string type, so if `oneElement.path` is a string value in your code then `path={path}` is correct per the docs. *However*, route path strings *can* contain [dynamic segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) which appear to incorrect for your specific use case. So this is more of a logical issue than it is a "syntax" issue. Does this make sense?

Comment: ok thanks for your answer

Comment: @loomi.dev Welcome, glad to help. Did my suggestion here actually address/resolve your question/issue?